# Useless use of (/) in void context

Tags: perl

When I try this code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print (44+66)/2;
```

It gave me:

**Useless use of division (/) in void context at p.pl line 3.**

But, after some tries, it worked by adding extra outer parentheses around the expression like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
print ((44+66)/2);
```

And it did work!

Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Deparse](https://perldoc.perl.org/B::Deparse) will give you more information about how perl is parsing your code:

```
perl -MO=Deparse p.pl
Useless use of division (/) in void context at p.pl line 3.
use warnings;
use strict;
print(110) / 2;
p.pl syntax OK
```

Here you can see that the expression in the parens was evaluated as expected (66+44 = 110).  But, then perl passes 110 as input to `print`, then tries to divide the output of `print` by 2.

Another helpful tool is [diagnostics](https://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics):

```
perl -Mdiagnostics p.pl
Useless use of division (/) in void context at p.pl line 3 (#1)
    (W void) You did something without a side effect in a context that does
    nothing with the return value, such as a statement that doesn't return a
    value from a block, or the left side of a scalar comma operator.  Very
    often this points not to stupidity on your part, but a failure of Perl
    to parse your program the way you thought it would.
```

It's great that you enabled `warnings` because it alerted you that there could be a problem with your code.  When we run the code, we get 110 as output, whereas you expected 55.

Answer (score 4):

The space between a function name and the opening parenthesis for the function call is optional. So when you write:

```perl
print (44+66)/2;
#    ^ optional space!
```

Perl is assuming that you want to divide `print(44+66)` by `2` and then ignore the answer. So Perl warns you about performing an unnecessary division operation.

```perl
# workaround
print( (44+66)/2 );

# other workaround
print +(44+66)/2;
```

Comment: Or `0.5*(44+66)` :)